# @Nullable NullPointerException

Tags: java

Obtengo un error en SonarQube con el código:

```
public String createKey(@Nullable String user) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  OkHttpClient client = apiClient.getHttpClient();
  byte[] crytopKey = generateKey(user, getSalt(user), KEY_SIZE);
  String hex = PasswordUtils.bytesToHex(crytopKey);
```

El error de sonar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer error se debe a que la variable user puede ser nulo, pero no entiendo por qué lo indica, cuando está anotado con @Nullable
Alguna sugerencia.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si llamas a `getSalt()` con una parámetro que puede ser `null` te generará una excepción `NullPointerException` en ese caso, que no estás ni propagando ni capturando con un bloque `try / catch`. Debes hacer una de las dos cosas para quitar el error.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: No, pero esta respuesta me parece muy buena : Una NPE se puede producir también aunque nunca "uses métodos o propiedades de una variable o expresión que vale null". Con throw new NullPointerException("Porque soy un pedante. Mira otro pato."); Seguiré investigando, gracias por tu tiempo.